# Image over another image in allegro5 (C++)

Tags: c++, image, background, allegro, allegro5

I have a problem with adding a background in my game. My code looks like that:

```
while (true)
{
    al_draw_bitmap(background, 0, 0, NULL);
    al_flip_display();
    some code(...);
    al_draw_bitmap(snake,0,0,NULL);
    /*drawing my snake's tail*/
    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));
    al_draw_bitmap(apple,0,0,NULL);
    al_flip_display();
}
```

And I have visible an apple and a black screen most of the time. 
I've been changing order of some lines in code and none of these combination worked (best case was when I had visible snake and background but there was no apple).
Before adding a background, my snake's tail sometimes disappered, but it wasn't very visible, and except that, everything seemed to be okay. 
Anyone knows how to add a background properly?
Or maybe it's fault of my computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once per draw loop, you should:

1. clear the display
2. draw your background
3. draw bitmaps on top of the background
4. flip the display

For example:

```
al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));
al_draw_bitmap(background, 0, 0, NULL);
al_draw_bitmap(apple,0,0,NULL);
al_draw_bitmap(snake,0,0,NULL);
al_flip_display();
```

Note that you should only call `al_flip_display` *once per draw loop*, after you have drawn everything for that loop. `al_clear_to_color` should be called first as it will wipe out everything you have drawn. In the example you gave, you are drawing your apple and snake to the same location, so I wouldn't be suprised if one is blocking part of the other.

Also, you probably don't want to stick your draw loop in a `while(true)` as the framerate will be unconstrained. That is, it will run as fast as it is allowed, and the framerate won't be consistent. The typical approach is to use an [event-driven draw loop](https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Allegro_5_Tutorial/Timers).